# Populate column with previous value partitioned by Account Number

Tags: sql, self-join

I'm unable to figure out how to do the following (see table attached).

----------GOAL----------

1. Trying to populate "ACS" in the Protocol2 Column
2. Trying to populate previous value in the Monitoring Column

----------TABLE-----------

[Table][image: 1]

----------CURRENT CODE----------

```
Drip2 as (
    Select
        AccountNumber,
        min(DateTime) as MinInfusionDateTime,
        max(DateTime) as MaxInfusionDateTime
    from
        HeparinDrip
    group by
        AccountNumber,
        DateTime
),
Drip3 as (
    Select
        Name,
        h1.AccountNumber,
        RxNumber,
        DateTime,
        Monitoring,
        Rate,
        Bolus,
        Case when AdminID = '1'
        and InfusionSeqID = '1'
        and Rate = '12' then 'ACS' when AdminID = '1'
        and InfusionSeqID = '1'
        and Rate = '18' then 'VTE' Else '' end as Protocol2,
        AdminID,
        InfusionSeqID
    from
        HeparinDrip h1
        inner join HeparinDrip2 h2 on (h1.AccountNumber = h2.AccountNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you can use `max()`.  Something like this:

```
select hd.*,
       max(protocol2) over (partition by name, accountnumber) as imputed_protocol2
from HeparinDrip hd;
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize there were two parts to this question.  You can do the other part using `lag(ignore nulls)`, but not all databases support that.  Instead, assign groups using a cumulative count and then shmear the value through the group:

```
select hd.*,
       max(protocol2) over (partition by name, accountnumber) as imputed_protocol2,
       max(monitoring) over (partition by name, accountnumber, grp) as imputed_monitoring
from (select hd.*,
             count(monitoring) over (partition by name, accountnumber order by datetime) as grp
      from HeparinDrip hd
     ) hd;
```

Comment: That worked! Any suggestions for: Trying to populate previous value in the Monitoring Column?

Comment: I did two CTE which made the 2nd part work!!
select * ,sum(Monitoring_aPTT_RASS2) over (order by Infusion_Lab_DateTime) as RunningTotal from HeparinDrip2)

,HeparinDrip4 as (select * ,max(Monitoring_aPTT_RASS) over (Partition by RunningTotal, GenericName, AccountNumber) as Monitoring_aPTT_RASS3
from HeparinDrip3)